# Arduino: How to serial.print / oled.print the current value (of an array)?

Tags: arduino

this is probably a Beginner Question.

I have found a LED sketch that includes various patterns, and you can cycle though them with a button, works fine. Now I wanted to upgrade that with an oled display and write name and number of the current pattern there. I can print the number ok, but trying to get the pattern name results in the error

> no matching function for call to 'println(void (*&)())'

The relevant code is this:

```
typedef void (*SimplePatternList[])();
SimplePatternList gPatterns = { PurpleRipple, twoDots, fillAndCC, blinkyblink2, spewFour, spew, confetti_GB, rainbow, confetti, sinelon, juggle };

uint8_t gCurrentPatternNumber = 0; // Index number of which pattern is current
```

Inside the loop there is this

```
 gPatterns[gCurrentPatternNumber]();
```

which appears to call the next pattern by number,so "0" would be "PurpleRipple" etc.

This here works for me, if gives me 0, 1, 2, 3 etc.:

```
oled.print(gCurrentPatternNumber);
```

This here doesn't, I get the mentioned error. I wanted to print "PurpleRipple", "twoDots", "fillAndCC" etc.

```
 oled.print(gPatterns[gCurrentPatternNumber]);
```

It's the same behaviour for serial.print and oled.print.

What is the right way to serial.print the function name of the current pattern?
Thanks :-)

Comment: those are function pointers, not function names

Comment: But the functions exist with these names: e.G. "void PurpleRipple()"

Comment: `void (*&)()` is a function that return nothing(i.e. void), the error message is telling you that there is no such `Serial.println()` overload [functions](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/Print.h#L77-L88) that take-in a function as the argument.

Comment: Sorry, my initial question was unclear, I edited it from "What is wrong?" to "What is the right way to serial.print the function name of the current pattern?"

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef void (*SimplePatternList[])();
SimplePatternList gPatterns = { PurpleRipple, twoDots, fillAndCC };
```

PurpleRipple (etc.) is a function, which does not return a text.
The name is only available in the source code, not in the compiled binary.

As these functions currently return nothing (void) you could modify them to return a const char* and actually return the text you want to see/display.

The side effect of doing fancy stuff with your LEDs can remain as is. And if you call the function and ignore the returned text pointer, nobody complains.

However, I fear these functions take a while until the LED show is over, which might be something different than simply return a text. So the text might only be available after the show finished :(

Alternatively, you might setup a separate array of texts

```
const char * fnames[] = {"PurpleRipple", "Two Dots", "Fill and CC" };
```

These texts are formally completely independent from the function names of course.

---

Added due to your comment:

You might combine name and function pointer in a struct, giving you a single array of namedPattern elements

using old fashioned `typedef` like this:

```
void pRipple() {
   Serial.print("Purple Ripple running");    
   delay(2000); Serial.println("done");
}
void oFunc() {}

typedef struct {const char* name; void (*f)();} namedPattern; 
namedPattern gPattern[] ={{"Purple Ripple", pRipple }, 
                          {"Other Function", oFunc }      };
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   Serial.println(gPattern[1].name); // Show a name
}

void loop() {
   gPattern[0].f(); // call the first function
   delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Great, the fnames solution works well. I treated gPatterns as an array, but it was something else. fnames is a real array :-)

Comment: FYI: Both are arrays. fnames is an array of texts (const char*), gPatterns is an array of void function().

Comment: Too bad that the name of the current gPattterns element cannot be extracted somehow. But your fnames solution works well.